# Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be available in order to run eclipse

Tags: java, adk

I downloaded the newest Android Development Kit and keep receiving this error. It then tells me that there is no virtual machine available in the path eclipse\jre\bin\javaw.exe in my current path. I cannot seem to get this to work. I have the newest JDK as well. I am trying to run this on a Windows 8.1 machine. Any suggestions?

Comment: have you restart your machine?

Comment: By "newest JDK" I hope you mean Java 7 or lower and not Java 8.  Windows 8 is a 64 bit operating system, so do you have the 64 bit Eclipse?

Comment: Yes, Java 7. And yes I do.

Answer (score 0):

Add vm param like this

```
-vm
C:\Java\JDK\1.6\bin\javaw.exe
```

to ecipse.ini. See http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini